# Django Pagination Where User Selects/Types Desired Page

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, pagination

I am looking to create a pagination like either of the following examples:

https://www.martindale.com/search/attorneys/?term=Bankruptcy%20near%20New%20York%2C%20USA (top right of search results)

https://www.adidas.com/us/superstar?start=0 (scroll to the bottom)

Where a user could either type in the page they want to go to and press enter or have a dropdown selection showing all the possible pages to choose from and then once selecting, automatically go to that page (the dropdown probably seems better to prevent users from typing a random set of numbers of characters into the input field). Otherwise the input field where a user types will need forms.py validation.

When attempting to do this, I ran into an issue not being able to use a template tag within forms.py. I was able to make a template for loop dropdown menu that loops through all the possible page numbers. But this for loop is not using forms.py which I don't think is desirable (because no validation). My pagination code is currently separate from forms.py or the form tag HTML.

I would still like to keep the current next, previous, first, and last links to appease those types of users. But if there are lots of pages of results, I want to give users freedom to quickly go to a desired page they want without clicking next or previous a bunch of times to get there.

How would I get the desired result similar to both of the links above?

Current HTML Pagination:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?{% url_replace paginator.first_page_number %}{{ page_obj.page_number }}1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?{% url_replace paginator.previous_page_number %}{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?{% url_replace paginator.next_page_number %}{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?{% url_replace paginator.last_page_number %}{{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

App_tags.py:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(context, next_page):
    query = context['request'].GET.copy().urlencode()

    if '&page=' in query:
        url = query.rpartition('&page=')[0] # equivalent to .split('page='), except more efficient 
    elif 'page=' in query:
        url = query.rpartition('page=')[0]
    else:
        url = query
    return f'{url}&page={next_page}'
```

Attempt Template For Loop Showing All Possible Pages:

```
<select class="form-control col-md-1" autocomplete="off">
{% for i in "x"|rjust:page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
<option> {{ forloop.counter }} </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Attempt Forms.py:

```
class CourseForm(forms.Form):

        page_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control col-md-1', 'autocomplete':'off', 'id':'title_contains', 'type':'search', 'placeholder': {{ page_obj.number }} }), required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CourseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['page_number'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = {{ page_obj.number }}
```